# Rider : keyboard shortcut to go to the next suggestion

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rider

Using Jetbrains rider on Linux.
The shortcut to go to the next warning is `F2` (the yellow ones) and that's very productive in refactoring existing code.

However, how do I go to the next suggestion (the green ones)? Haven't been able to figure this out from the [Official Rider Keymap Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keymap_Rider.html) hence the question.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Design_time_Inspection.html

Answer (score 2):

On Mac, you can do this with `fn + option + Down Arrow`, or `option + Page Down`, if you prefer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the code analysis indicator, and select "Go to next problem" ([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html)). This should allow navigating to code issues with the "Warning" severity level.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it still doesn't focus unused code (gray out) nor warnings (yellow zigzag underline). Might be something to report to Jetbrains anyway. I noticed the doc is for IDEA so it may differ slightly, but that's still odd.